# "cross", crossunder and crossover function of pinescript in python

Tags: python, function, python-imaging-library, pine-script, timeserieschart

I am trying to convert a pine script into python.

in pine I use function cross, crossunder and crossover for checking the if a particular series has crossed the other (say sma and ema crossing) over other to arrive at entry positions for stock.

I am not able to find equivalent function in python.

can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use these ones. Works for me.

```
import pandas as pd

def crossover_series(x: pd.Series, y: pd.Series, cross_distance: int = None) -> pd.Series:
    shift_value = 1 if not cross_distance else cross_distance
        return (x > y) & (x.shift(shift_value) < y.shift(shift_value))

def crossunder_series(x: pd.Series, y: pd.Series, cross_distance: int = None) -> pd.Series:
    shift_value = 1 if not cross_distance else cross_distance
    return (x < y) & (x.shift(shift_value) > y.shift(shift_value))
```